# Found HTMLElement with tabindex will not focus()

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus, tabindex, htmlelements

I have an `HTMLElement`, which is found and set in a variable that will not focus when using `.focus()`. Since this is an Angular app, I have tried using `nativeElement` to focus, but the element is not found.

Acceptable answers can use either method and maybe others, as long as it doesn't involve using an extra library like jQuery.

```
<mat-checkbox
    [ngModel]="value"
    [tabIndex]="tabIndex"
    [id]="tabbableId"
    (keydown.enter)="toggleCheckAndEmit()"
    #htCheckbox
></mat-checkbox>

export class MatCheckboxWrapperComponent {

    @ViewChild('htCheckbox', {static: true}) public htCheckbox?: ElementRef;
    
    public tabbableId: string = 'tabbable-'
    
    @Input()
    public tabIndex: number = 0;

    public toggleCheckAndEmit(): void {
        this.value = !this.value;
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);

        const checkbox = document.getElementById(this.tabbableId);

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.htCheckbox && this.htCheckbox.nativeElement) {
                // this code is unreachable
                this.htCheckbox.nativeElement.focus();
            } else {
               // this.htCheckbox.nativeElement is never found :(
            }
            if (checkbox) {
                //mat-checkbox is always found BUT
                checkbox.focus();
                // document.activeElement is still <body> :( 
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me. I implemented `NgAfterViewInit` to run your method and refactored a little bit. We can access elements in template after their rendered via NgAfterViewInit (the earliest). We then reference to the element as HTMLElement, instead of ElementRef.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzf4pd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This solution works and more importantly, it made me aware that my HTML element was being destroyed and created again, therefore causing me refocus of the element to fail. So while this does not fix my issue, it is the correct solution and thus deserves the green check.